# Giving week number and year find the first day and last day of week

Tags: java, calendar

I have week number and year, and I would like to get the date of the first day of week and the last one, this is my code, it gives me wrong result, please tell me what I'm I doing wrong. thanks in advance.

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); 
String start ="";
String end ="";
int week = 38;
int yeat = 2016;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year); 
// firt day of week
start = dt.format(calendar.getTime());
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
//last day of week
end = dt.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to calculate Date from ISO8601 week number in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25084576/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Correct the DateFormatter syntax, month should be in capital case
- Get the date for Sunday and Saturday in that particular week for the
  year passed.

  ```
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
       String start ="";
       String end ="";
       int week = 38;
       int year = 2016;
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year); 
       calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
       calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
        start = dt.format(calendar.getTime());
       calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SATURDAY);
         end = dt.format(calendar.getTime());
       System.out.println(start+" |"+end);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java 8+, you could use the built-in week-date formatter:

```
int week = 38;
int year = 2016;
String weekYear = year + "-W" + week + "-7"; //2016-W38-7
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(year + "-W" + week + "-7", ISO_WEEK_DATE); //2016-09-25
```

Note: the `-7` at the end of the string represents the last day of the week (i.e. sunday).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); 
String start ="";
String end ="";
int week = 38;
int year = 2016;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year); 

// firt day of week
Calendar cal = calendar;
while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
}
start = dt.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(start);

Calendar cal1 = calendar;
while (cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
    cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
//last day of week
end = dt.format(cal1.getTime());
System.out.println(end);
```